# Is [var = modify(var)] a bad practice?

Tags: java

As a simplified example,  given an array of numbers.  I need to apply some value filters.

So what I'm doing currently:

Original given array: `List<Integer>originalList;`

How I construct my filtering methods:

```
List<Integer> removeNegativeNumber(final List<Integer> numberList) {
 return FluentIterable.from(numberList).filter(rule).toList();
}
```

How I use:

```
List<Integer> filteredList = removeNegativeNumber(originalList);
 filteredList = removeOddNumber(filteredList);
 filteredList = removeZeroNumber(filteredList);
```

My feeling tells me that it can be done better. But I don't know how. Can someone give me advises, recommendations for improving my code ?

Comment: what you want is `FluentIterable.from(numberList).filter(rmNegative).filter(rmZero).filter(rmOdd).toList();`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider lambdas and `Stream#filter()` if you're using Java 8:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
List<Integer> filteredList = list.stream()
        .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
        .filter(i -> i != 0)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(filteredList);
```

Or using `IntStream`:

```
IntStream stream = IntStream.of(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
IntStream filteredStream = stream.filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
        .filter(i -> i != 0);
filteredStream.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Javadoc:

1. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html
2. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-

Comment: This requires autoboxing in more that one place. Better convert to an `IntStream` and back for more performance.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @4castle, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could chain the statements together, such as like this:

```
List<Integer> filteredList = removeZeroNumber(
                               removeOddNumber(
                                 removeNegativeNumber(originalList)));
```

But that is wasteful because it maps back and forth from a `List` to `FluentIterable` with each method. You're better off chaining the underlying `FluentIterable` methods:

```
List<Integer> filteredList = FluentIterable.from(numberList)
                                           .filter(i -> i > 0)
                                           .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
                                           .toList();
```

If you're using Java 8 though, an `IntStream` should be used to prevent repeated autoboxing:

```
List<Integer> filteredList = originalList.stream()
                                         .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                                         .filter(i -> i > 0)
                                         .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
                                         .boxed()
                                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @tobias_k Yes, I was thinking with Streams. It's updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to retain neither the original nor transitional values, you could use methods with side-effects rather than a pure function :

```
removeNegativeNumber(theOnlyList);
removeOddNumber(theOnlyList);
removeZeroNumber(theOnlyList);
// now the list only contains positive non-zero even numbers
```

These methods could be implemented by using an `Iterator`'s `remove()` method when its current element does not satisfy the conditions.

---

If you need to retain the original values, but not the transitional values, you should use pure functions and link them as described by 4castle. As an addition, a more modern way to do so would be to use the `Stream` API :

```
List<Integer> filteredList = originalList.stream()
                                         .filter(i -> i >= 0)
                                         .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
                                         .filter(i -> i != 0)
                                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```